# How can I read in a filename in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

this is the format that I need it to be in for the project.

```
Enter file name: filename.txt.
```

My code so far is:

```
choice(2, X) :- 
  nl, write('\tStore roster to a file:'),nl, write('\tEnter file name: '),read(N),
  open(N,write,Stream), write(Stream, X), write('Roster stored.'),nl,nl,menu(X).
```

This gives the error:

```
ERROR: Stream user_input:21:102 Syntax error: Operator expected
```

I'd appreciate any help.  What I'm trying to do here, is take a user input filename then create the file and write a list of lists to it.

Answer (score 1):

When I try the clause above I get:

```
?- choice(2, X).

    Store roster to a file:
    Enter file name: 'filename.txt'.
Roster stored.
```

I suspect that the error is that you're not inputting the filename between single quotes to ensure that it will be read as an atom as required by the first argument of the standard `open/3` predicate.

If you modify your clause to:

```
choice(2, X) :- 
  nl, write('\tStore roster to a file:'),nl, write('\tEnter file name: '),read(N0),
  term_to_atom(N0,N),
  open(N,write,Stream), write(Stream, X), write('Roster stored.'),nl,nl,menu(X).
```

You can then do without the single quotes, however:

```
?- choice(2, X).

    Store roster to a file:
    Enter file name: filename.txt.
Roster stored.
```

Comment: I have no doubt that's the issue.  The sample output our teacher wants us to match has him input the filename without quotes.

Comment: if my input were filename it'd be fine.  I have no idea how to handle filename.extension though.

Comment: Which SWI-Prolog version are you using?

Comment: The trouble of the solutions proposed by me and by Grzegorz is that they use proprietary SWI-Prolog predicates (`term_to_atom/2` and `read_line_to_codes/2`), hurting portability. But maybe that's not an issue in your case?

Comment: My intructor has been consistently against using proprietary libraries for the other languages we've worked on.  I'll have to ask to be sure.  I'll pretend for now that a filename can't have a '.' in it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution to this problem. Newly created `read_string/1` reads name as it is (you don't need to use single quotes). And also I'm closing the stream by using `close/1` which is very important because without it data may NOT be written to disk. (In my case on Windows8 and SWI-Prolog 6.6.4 it is NOT written.)

```
read_string(String) :-
    current_input(Input),
    read_line_to_codes(Input, Codes),
    string_codes(String, Codes).

choice(2, X) :-
  nl, write('\tStore roster to a file:'),nl, write('\tEnter file name: '),read_string(N),open(N,write,Stream), write(Stream, X), close(Stream), write('Roster stored.'),nl,nl,menu(X).
```

UPDATE:

Sample input and output:

```
?- choice(2, test).

        Store roster to a file:
        Enter file name: test.txt
Roster stored.
```

And contents of `test.txt`: `test`.

Comment: While you're at it, you can enclose opening and closing the stream in `setup_call_cleanup/3` to make sure the stream is closed even if the write operations fail.